# Convert Hashtable elements to List

Tags: c#, linq, list, casting, hashtable

I have this

hashtable has a

```
key "ids" and its values are [1,2,3]

List<long> ids= (List<long>)hashtable["ids"];
```

an error occurs when trying to cast. It says

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]'.
```

I've been stuck for hours, any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't JArray have a method like ToList()?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Convert Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to a list of specific object type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565245/convert-newtonsoft-json-linq-jarray-to-a-list-of-specific-object-type)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I actually tried but I can't seem to get the syntax correctly.

Comment: Your hashtable looks like a JObject or JToken. @Tims answer looks right on the money.Try something like `var list = hashtable["ids"].ToObject<List<long>>()`

Comment: Although is is fairly clear now, you should have specified the generic type parameters of `hashtable` in your question.

Comment: @Enigmativity I can see that based from most of the comments, I'll try better next time ! :D 

nphx yah I'm sorry, the comment below reminded me to import.

Comment: @bottlenecked Im not sure but its not defined on my end =/ but thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you wrote in your question what are the values you expect to get and the definition of your hashtable.
Assuming You are trying to get `[1,2,3]` and your 'Value' is an array of `long`, try:

```
List<long> ids= hashtable["ids"].ToList();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it says it does not have a definition for 'toList'. 

Although ((List<long>)hashtable["ids"]).ToList<long>;

but this time it says cannot convert method group ToList to a non-delagate type List<long>

Comment: @user3770093 `ToList` is with a capital `T`. Also make sure you are using you are using linq: `using System.Linq;`. If this still is not working for you, please post the declaration of your hashtable.

Comment: Hey thanks man! I found a work around based from your comment, and yes I forgot to import System.linq ugh clumsy of me. Thanks Man!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static List<dynamic> ToDynamicList(this Hashtable ht)
    {
        var result = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in ht)
        {
            result.Add(new { key = de.Key, value = de.Value });
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.