# How to tell JSON.NET to deserialize JArray to a List<object> when object type is provided?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Let's have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    public object Any;
}
```

This class accepts anything in the field `Any`.

When I call:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{any: 5}")
```

`Any` contains `System.Int64`.

However, when I call:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{any: [5]}")
```

`Any` contains `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`.

How to configure JSON.NET so that in this case  `Any` would contain `List<object>`?

**CLARIFICATION:**

There could be anything, I can call:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{any: 'c'}")
```

or

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{any: ['c', 5]}")
```

**More clarification:**

I would like to tell somehow to JSON.NET (maybe using JsonSerializerSettings):

> When you encounter `object` and JSON contains an array, deserialize that
>   to (for instance) `List<object>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Comment: If `Any` is just `5` and not `[5]`, would you like it to be a `List<System.Int64>` too?

Comment: @Daniel No, since there could be [5, 'x']. (Therefore, I have put `object` there.)

Comment: You can mark a constructor with JsonConstructorAttribute (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) which will tell it to use that constructor when deserializing the object. You could then put any logic you want in there. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Chris I cannot annotate the particular classes, I need to specify that as a 'global' behavior. See "more clarification".

Comment: @TN.: I had a suspicion that might be the case. There are overloads of DeserializeObject that take JsonConverters that might do what you want but I've not used them. In general JsonConverters override read/write behaviour so should be able to do what you want but I can't tell you much more on how to use them. (Apologies if you've already checked if these overloads will help you) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254872/using-json-net-converters-to-deserialize-properties may be of interest on this topic (may even be a duplicate)

Comment: @Chris I have already written few converters, however I do not know, how to specify that it should be invoked only when JSON contains an array (and type of member is object). Or how to fallback to the default behavior when JSON contains (for instance) a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is probably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565245/convert-newtonsoft-json-linq-jarray-to-a-list-of-specific-object-type)

Your `[5]` is an array. All you have to do is to cast it to a list.

---

You could also create your own converter, like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485587/2097240)

Comment: I do not want to retraverse the structure and check and cast all fields with object type.

Comment: How to specify that a convert should be invoked only when JSON contains an array (and type of member is object)? Or how to fallback to the default behavior when JSON contains (for instance) a string?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, I have mocked the following solution:

```
public class MyObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(object);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.StartArray:
                return JToken.Load(reader).ToObject<List<object>>(); 
            case Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.StartObject:
                return JToken.Load(reader).ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(); 
            default:
                if (reader.ValueType == null && reader.TokenType != Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.Null)
                    throw new NotImplementedException("MyObjectConverter");
                return reader.Value;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("MyObjectConverter");
    }
}
```

Problem of this solution is that it must handle the other types as well. It could fail when reader.TokenType is neither `StartArray` nor `StartObject` and reader.ValueType is null. Hopefully someone will provide a better solution.

Comment: You don't need to conver all types. You just need to convert the types you desire. If I understood it well, you just need to implement the `Array` case, any other case you just return the object as it is and JSON will do the rest. (It was able to manage those types without a converter, right?)

Comment: However, where I get 'the object' for the other cases?

Comment: ToObject<object> does not deserialize the nested arrays properly (e.g. `[1, [5, 3]]` or `[1, {bar: [4]}]`). The same problem has currently the solution above.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions if you just remove that `if`?

Comment: Maybe not, but want to know whether reader contains `null` in `Value`, because it should be there or not. But you can just ignore that if. Problem is that `JToken.Load(reader).ToObject<List<object>>()` does not process the nested array and maybe other JsonConvertors which are configured.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with a JsonConverter. The converter below converts JArrays to lists of Objects when the any field is a JArray and falls back to the default behavior for any in all other cases. Based on your description, this is exactly what you are looking for. I suspect the code could be improved, but this should put you the the path to a solution:

```
public class ListJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var theFoo = new Foo();

        dynamic dynamicObject = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        if (dynamicObject.any.GetType() == typeof (JArray))
        {
            var items = new List<object>();

            foreach (var item in dynamicObject.any)
            {
                items.Add(item);
            }

            theFoo.Any = items;
        }
        else
        {
            theFoo.Any = dynamicObject.any.Value;
        }

        return theFoo;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (Foo);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var bar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{any: ['c', 5]}", new ListJsonConverter());
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but the `Foo` is just an example. I cannot hardwire the converter for a particular class (`Foo`) and property (`Any`).

Comment: Do you mean, you want that to work with any kind of object? Like Foo1, Foo2, Foo3 and any other?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I have tried to mock the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31131934/121968.