# Convert C# Hashtable value to List

Tags: c#, json, post, casting, hashtable

I am sending a post request from Javascript to C#

Javascript

```
var name = "doe";
var ids = [1,2,3];

var parameter = {
ids : ids,
name : name,
groups: groups
}
```

C#

```
public string sampleMethod (Hashtable hashtable)
{
string name = hashtable["name"].toString();//works well
List<long> ids = (List<long>)hashtable["ids"];//doesnt work
}
```

I just want to get the values [1,2,3] from hashtable["ids"] then convert it to long;

Comment: I think long cannot be converted directly and thus it need to convert first 
`(List<long>) Convert.ToLong(hashtable["ids"])` something of this sorf

Comment: Are you sure that the javascript value `[1, 2, 3]` is represented as `List<long>`? I would suggest it is represented as array - and maybe of int instead of long.

Comment: Agreeing with @wudzik 
The problem and solution are essentially the same.

Comment: @wudzik This is not a duplicate at all. He's trying to cast a the value(s) of the hashtable, not the keys.

Comment: Try this: `List<int> ids = (List<int>)hashtable["ids"];` or `var ids = (int[])hashtable["ids"];`

Comment: Hi everyone, I appreciate all your answers. 
@Rob yes I am trying to cast the values ( or even just retrieve it). 
Verarind even if I try to cast it to array it throws an error regarding "Unable to cast object to type 'Newtonsoft.Json' etc..."

Comment: What are you using on the c# side to receive the post request?  ASP.NET MVC?  ASP.NET Web Api?  Also, what serializer?

Comment: @user3770093 Try `hashtable["ids"].GetType()` to get a hint of the type that's stored in the hashtable. Maybe after that you know what type to cast.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
 Array ids = (Array)hashtable["ids"];
```

or

```
List<int> ids = (List<int>)hashtable["ids"];
```

or

```
 int[] ids = (int[])hashtable["ids"];
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.

I think I cant simply cast it, I'm trying to do some deserialization at the moment.

Comment: @user3770093 You know the type already? Cast to it and call [`ToObject<List<in>>()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13565373/2729609)