# Map JSON object to c# class property

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

I'm getting a bunch of JSON data back from a 3rd party API like this:

```
returnValue = data["value"].ToObject<List<T>>();
```

All but one of the fields are just basic name:value pairs like this:

```
"Name":"Value"
```

I map the values I need to a class like this:

```
public sealed class Project
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProjectDateLocal { get; set; }
    public string ParentFolderName { get; set; }
    public string ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    //causing trouble
    public Int32 ProjectTypeId { get; set; }

    public string PlayerUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return "http://em.edu.edu/prj/Play/" + this.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

However, one name:value pair is complicated like this:

```
"CustomFieldValues":[
        {
          "FieldName":"ProjectTypeId","FieldDefinitionId":"37a2ffeb3bd441f6a60158458910a04d40","DataType":"Integer","Value":"100105"
        }
      ]
```

I only need the FieldName(ProjectTypeId) and Value, is there a way to get just that have the class recognize that and set it in my ProjectTypeId property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Json.net to deserialize `JsonConvert.Deserialize<Project>(jsonStringContent)`

Json.net will go multi levels, just add a new class and have your `Project` have that property.

```
public class CustomFieldValue
{
    public string FieldName {get;set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

and add a list of them to your Project.

```
public sealed class Project
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<CustomFieldValue> CustomFieldValues { get; set; }
}
```

Json.net won't have any problem with it. If you don't add `FieldDefinitionId`, etc then Json.net will just ignore it.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean use: JsonConvert.Deserialize<Project>(jsonStringContent) , instead of: returnValue = data["value"].ToObject<List<T>>();

Comment: In the above, <T> = <Project>

Comment: I'm not sure where your stringified json is in. My guess is it is in data["value"], right? if so then returnValue = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Project>(data["value"])

Comment: Did you mean to use 'JsonConvert.DeserializeObject'?  I couldn't find JsonConvert.Deserialize.  Thanks.

Comment: This won't work because 'returnValue' needs to be type System.Collections.Generic.List<T>

Comment: if your json is an array of Projects, then use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(data["value"])

Answer (score 3):

As @viggity stated, you can use Newtonsoft for your problem and the solution provided is good. The only thing you have to do is provide a good string json to the Deserializer.

If you want a simpler solution why don't you use `data["value"].ToObject<List<Project>>()` ? 
Note: Assigning attributes like `[JsonProperty("FieldNameFromJson")]` is ussefull for mappings.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565245/convert-newtonsoft-json-linq-jarray-to-a-list-of-specific-object-type) for more info about how you can do this.