# LINQ on JArray always returning null

Tags: json, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to parse some `Json` in `Xamarin.Forms`

I'm pretty new to Xamarin, though not to .net

Here's my simple dimple code

```
        var htc = new HttpClient();
        var rsp = await htc.GetStringAsync("myurl.com");
        JArray lists = JArray.Parse(rsp);
        var c = lists.Count();
        var l = lists.ToList();
        var w=lists.Where(x => true);
```

Even though c returns the correct count of items in the list, l & w are both null

How come? and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

PS. What I'm really trying to do is bind a `ListView` to a `JArray`, but it seems impossible directly,(`Text={Binding MyPropertyName}` crashes the app). so I'm trying to run a `Select` on the `JArray` to convert to a `KeyValuePair`. If you have any ideas to bind directly, that would be best!

**UPDATE**

The issue seems even odder

I tried this

```
 var kvlist = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        foreach (JObject ll in lists)
        {
            kvlist.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(ll["Name"].ToString(), ll["Name"].ToString()));
        }
```

Here at least the iteration works nicely, but the kvlist is null the entire time. Trying to evaluate the kvlist variable, I get:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type
>   'Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror'.

What can the matter be?

Thanks again!

Comment: Which .NET JSON parsing library is being used? Perhaps the relevant tag should be added.

Comment: _`kvlist` is `null` the entire time_ -- The call to `.Add` falls with a null-reference exception?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to indicate that JArray has properties for .Count, but no overload method because it does not implement IEnumerable, however as alluded to in the comments, it does implement the JToken type (which JArray is a collection of) and implements IEnumerable.
See the following documentation for JToken: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm
and JArray respectively:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm

The preferred mechanism is to create a strong type and then run .ToObject();
You can access JArray.ChildrenTokens which may help

Comment: Hi. Thanks. `ToObject` seems to work for a single item, is there a way to convert a `JArray` to a list<T>? thanks.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565245/convert-newtonsoft-json-linq-jarray-to-a-list-of-specific-object-type :). Just a note, the KeyValuePair struct goes a bit funny with JSON, as fundamentally objects are notated as a kvp.
Often in web apps you have to create a strong type to prevent the key being prop name. To some this is desired behaviour.

Comment: I think `Count`, `First` and `Last` are the only such properties (and they're not methods, so they can't even take a `Predicate<JToken>` like the standard [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count), [`First`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first) and [`Last`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last). All other LINQ methods apply because `JArray` implements `IEnumerable<JToken>`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, they exist as properties much like on List<T>.Count property, but also List<T> has the Count method overload due to IEnumerable<T>, whereas the JToken can itself be an array, that's why I suspect IEnumerable is implemented on this level as opposed to JArray. Will update answer.

Comment: Just to remove any ambiguity it implements IEnumerable<JToken>, and has a property available of ChildrenTokens.

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly call `.ToList` on `object` type of `JArray` rather you should `Select` `List` of type you need. For ex.

```
var l = lists.Select(c => new MyList
{
    Item1 = c.Value<int>("ItemName1"),
    Item2 = c.Value<string>("ItemName2")
}).ToList(); //Replce MyList with your class name
```

On the second case where `w` is `null`, after getting list `l` you need to specify attribute, based of what you are using `where` clause. For ex.

```
var w=l.Where(x =>x.isAdmin==true); //l is list you selected above
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually how i started off. but the result is always null. So I posted some simpler variations. Any Ideas?

Comment: In answer I am selecting `ItemName1`,  `ItemName1` this should available in your `JArray` lists & need to give accurate type as well like `int` `string`. Have you created class with same fields what `JArray` returning?

Comment: Hi. It never goes into the iteration, it just skips to the next line. I guess thats becaus lists is null. Tough I dont know why. Did you see what i wrote about the Debugger error?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can use code below to convert a `JArray` to a `list<T>`:

```
List<T> t =lists.ToObject<List<T>>();
```

Refer: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ToObjectType.htm

You could also use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert it directly into the desired type. You have to define a `jsonModel` class with the same structure of your `json` fisrtly.

```
List<jsonModel> modelList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonModel>>(jsonStr);
```

Refer :https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm