# Swagger API Not Indicating Type Returned

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I am attempting to use a Swagger API.

This is an endpoint that I am trying to call...

https://asp.calibersoftware.com/capi2_APISandbox/swagger/ui/index#!/Client/Client_GetClientList

When i look at swagger it doesn't appear to indicate what will be returned.

When I generate a .net client for it all return types are "objects"

for example this is what gets generated for this endpoint:

```
public static async Task<object> GetClientListAsync(this IClient operations, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (var _result = await operations.GetClientListWithHttpMessagesAsync(null, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
         return _result.Body;
    }
}
```

Is this because I am doing something wrong or is the API missing the information?

I have "guessed" that the response will be a List of "Clients" but when i run this code:

```
List<Client> clientsList = (List<Client>)await client.GetClientListAsync();
```

I get the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Caliber.API.Model.Client]'.

Comment: The response will send back the data in JSON format, so you need clientList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Client>>(await client.GetClientListAsync());

Comment: Yes the API definition is missing info about response payload. As for your 2nd question - see [Convert Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to a list of specific object type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13565245/113116)