# c# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a string `Json` to a `List`. So first I converted it into a `JObject` using below code:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(stringJson);
```

**And I get below data:**

```
{
  "userHBList": [
    {
      "userTO": {
        "userId": 31234,
        "applicationId": 28,
        "username": "20240201-03.teena@sitepm.us",
        "password": "",
        "email": "20240201-03.teena@sitepm.us",
        "firstName": "teena",
        "lastName": ""
      },
      "verificationStatus": false,
      "companyList": [
        {
          "companyId": 75109,
          "title": "Jane-30984-Siya jewellers"
        }
      ],
      "phoneList": null,
      "userPhoneList": [
        {
          "userPhoneId": 801,
          "entity": "user",
          "entityId": 31234,
          "isd": "+1",
          "phoneNumber": "6876535689"
        }
      ],
      "profileEditable": true
    },
    {
      "userTO": {
        "userId": 31235,
        "applicationId": 28,
        "username": "20240201-04.riya@sitepm.us",
        "password": "",
        "email": "20240201-04.riya@sitepm.us",
        "firstName": "riya",
        "lastName": ""
      },
      "verificationStatus": false,
      "companyList": [
        {
          "companyId": 75109,
          "title": "Jane-30984-Siya jewellers"
        }
      ],
      "phoneList": null,
      "userPhoneList": [
        {
          "userPhoneId": 802,
          "entity": "user",
          "entityId": 31235,
          "isd": "+1",
          "phoneNumber": "9484648483"
        }
      ],
      "profileEditable": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I tried to convert it into `List` using below code:

```
List<UserHBList> userHBLists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserHBList>>(json.ToString());
```

But I a getting below exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CallerBee.Model.DirectoryResponse+UserHBList]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'userHBList', line 2, position 15. at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[List`1](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[List`1](String value)

Is any issue in the data format? I suspect on the key outside of the list `"userHBList"`, do we need that there?

Comment: The JSON you've presented is a single object, not a list. You probably want to deserialize into a "root" object which *contains* a `List<UserHBList>`. Or as you've already got a `JObject`, you *could* convert the `json["userHBList"]` JArray as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565245.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please post it as your answer. I used the root class name and now I am able to deserialize.

Comment: I suspect this is actually a duplicate of many, many similar questions. I'll try to find one.

Comment: (I had a quick look, but couldn't find  good duplicate. There are so many JSON topics using similar keywords... so I've added an answer, but if anyone else finds a duplicate, I think it would be fine to close this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you've presented is a single object, not a list. The simplest fix for this is to create a "root" class which *contains* a `List<UserHBList>`. For example:

```cs
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("userHBList")]
    public List<UserHBList> Users { get; set; }
}
```

You can then just directly deserialize to a `Root` (no need to go via `JObject`):

```cs
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(stringJson);
```

You can then use `root.Users` to get at the list.